# Failed to Install YII framework in windows?

Tags: php, yii

I am new to php and trying to create my first hello world application using yii i have visited this site [YII INSTALLATION](http://tommasodargenio.com/tutorial-8-easy-steps-to-create-a-web-application-with-yii-part-one-53.htm) and following tutorial.

But when i am writing "**cd yiic webapp Helloworld** " in CMD i am getting "The System cannot find the specified path " and i stuck here can someone please help me how to resolve this issue  Where the path of my Wamp is **"C:/wamp/www/yii-1.1.8.r3324/yii-1.1.8.r3324/framework "** its working fine till this point in **CMD** but after this line when trying to execute "cd yiic webapp Helloworld"  i am getting error  "**The System cannot find the specified path**"

EDIT :
[image]
[image: YIIC PATH]

Comment: Where on that page did you see that you should write `cd yiic webapp Helloworld` ? You're basically mixing up two commands there.

Comment: when i am writing single command cd yiic webapp i am also getting same error

Comment: See [Alireza Fallah's answer below](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21821515/1233508), first you need to `cd` to the directory where the framework's `yiic` file is, then you need `yiic webapp Helloworld`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

no need to add `./`

just run this line

```
yiic webapp c:/wamp/www/Helloworld/
```

have a look at this http://technet.weblineindia.com/web/how-to-create-your-first-yii-application-in-just-4-steps/

Update:

You need to run the command with php check this http://www.larryullman.com/2009/10/31/getting-started-with-the-yii-framework/

Run this command

```
C:\wamp\bin\php\phpX.X.X\php.exe yiic webapp c:/wamp/www/Helloworld/
```

make sure to correct the `php.exe` path

Comment: still error "The system cannot find the path specified "  can some one let me know may i need to add anything else in system variables

Comment: @user3233280 the system says they dont find `c:/wamp/www/Helloworld/` did you tried making a folder in your `www` root with the name `Helloworld`

Comment: try making the folder first, I think you didn't open your command prompt with the `run as administrator user`

Comment: you already have the folder `Helloworld`? with `H` capital ??

Comment: ok try to close the command prompt and start it as an administrator and try again

Comment: yes with H capital and run as administrator with same error

Comment: first of all move the framewrok from `/www/yii-1.1.8.r3324/yii-1.1.8.r3324/framework` to `/www/yii_1_1_8/framework` for your own good.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/47621/discussion-between-zzlalani-and-user3233280)

Answer (score 2):

I followed all of the answer and question on above still my friend user3233280 getting the same error because he is trying to see the hello world directly from cmd.I guess he dose not understand what and how the Yii application generally execute.First of all I can request to  user3233280 to read clearly all the tutorials the official site of Yii Framework
Like :

1. http://www.yiiframework.com/tutorials/
2. http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/blog/
3. http://www.larryullman.com/series/learning-the-yii-framework/

Also I can ask you one question after all these that have you set PHP engine path and the Yii bat file path in environment variable...? because it needs to set before running the yii application .

Also You can follow Below Url:

[How to Install Yii Application in windows-7/8](http://jyotiloppy.blogspot.in/2014/02/how-to-instal-yii-application-in-wamp.html)

Answer (score 1):

First you must execute this command :

```
cd c:/wamp/www/yii-1.1.8.r3324/yii-1.1.8.r3324/framework
```

And then this one :

```
yiic webapp c:/wamp/www/Helloworld/
```

Comment: cd path to app or cd path to www root

Comment: may i need to write this in single line with cd yiic webapp /wamp/www/Helloworld/ ?

Comment: i am getting same error when trying to write line with cd ?

Comment: no no no, forget about `cd yiic webapp /wamp/www/Helloworld/`, just do what I said

Comment: i am present at framework then trying to write ./yiic webapp ......what u told getting error

Comment: So when you try `./yiic webapp c:/wamp/www/Helloworld/` , what error do you get ?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/47620/discussion-between-user3233280-and-alireza-fallah)

Answer (score 0):

```
cd C:\wamp\www\yii-1.1.8.r3324\yii-1.1.8.r3324\framework && yiic ......
```

you also can type `help cd` to get a reference about the command `cd`.  if you try to execute 2 command at the same time, add "&&" between them

Comment: I **think** you didn't understand the question.

Answer (score 0):

Use yiic.bat instead yiic

```
cd c:\wamp\www\yii-1.1.8.r3324\yii-1.1.8.r3324\framework

yiic.bat webapp c:\wamp\www\Helloworld
```

Comment: the `yiic` is `exe` btw